# Объединиение профилей SO и HC

Tags: поддержка, хэшкод, миграция

Интересует следующее:

1. я думал при переезде профиль с HC полностью объединиться с профилем на SO. Но мне похоже просто дали бонус к репутации в моем старом профиле на SO. Так и должно быть или профили станут единым целым после окончательного переезда?
2. у меня ник написан кириллицей, хотя даже на HC он был написан латинскими символами. Это как то можно исправить? Кстати, судя по всему, проблема с кириллицей и тут сказалась: [image]

Answer (score 5):

Скорее всего текущая миграция является финальной. Во время миграции мы нашли порядка 5К пользователей, у которых уже есть учетная запись Stack Exchange.

Бонусов за миграцию нет! На Stack Overflow действует другая система оценки за голоса за/против, принятие ответов и т.д. Мы не импортировали репутацию, мы импортировали действия, пересчитывая репутацию на лету согласно правилам, действующим в Сети.

Параметры вашей учетной записи можно изменить в соответствующем разделе (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/3839).

**Обновление**

Постарался раскрыть тему объединения учётных записей более подробно в [этом сообщении](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/24/).

Comment: если бы все так просто было http://take.ms/gJXDp

Comment: Исследую вопрос.

Comment: аналогичная проблема

Comment: @andreich Обновил ответ.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я видел это и это не работает, к сожалению.

Comment: В этом случае, пожалуйста, напишите мне на почту (или в чат) ссылки на ваши учетные записи.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я хотел бы уточнить момент с одинаковым доменом. Дело в том, что на тут мой аккаунт находится по такому адресу: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/3839/andreich а на SO по такому http://stackoverflow.com/users/1654690/andreich если у первого убрать субдомен "ru", то будет совершенно другой человек, не я, а если добавить во второй ссылке, то учетки такой и нет еще

Comment: Проверил еще раз. На самом деле у вас все отлично сработало. Ваши учетные записи были объединены. Пожалуйста, [взгляните сюда](http://stackexchange.com/users/1820521/andreich?tab=accounts).

Answer (score 2):

С точки зрения StackExchange сети, StackOverflow на русском является отдельным от StackOverflow сайтом таким же как например, AskUbuntu, SuperUser, то есть пользовательский идентификатор, репутация, имя пользователя, итд являются отдельными.

При успешном объединении учётных записей вопросы, ответы, комментарии, возможно другие действия переносятся с ХэшКод на StackOverflow на русском, при этом *сетевой профиль* должен совпадать с учётной записью на StackOverflow (сами учётные записи разные), то есть *Достижения* и *Личные сообщения* (вверху слева динамически обновляющиеся списки) должны содержать данные как со stackoverflow так и ru.stackoverflow.