# Как начать пользоваться Stack Overflow на русском, имея учётную запись на ХэшКоде?

Tags: поддержка, хэшкод, миграция

У меня есть учётная запись с форума ХэшКод. Каким образом мне следует начать пользоваться Stack Overflow на русском так, чтобы не потерять все заданные вопросы, опубликованные ответы и репутацию?

Answer (score 22):

Пожалуйста, следуйте следующим рекомендациям.

1. Перейдите на страницу восстановления доступа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery.
2. Введите в форму адрес почты, который вы использовали на ХэшКоде.
3. Нажмите “Отправить письмо для восстановления доступа” (рис. 1).
4. Следуйте рекомендациям указанным в письме (рис. 2).

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Рис. 1

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Рис. 2

Будьте внимательны. **Данные шаги должны быть первыми. Выполните их до того, как вы попробуете войти в систему**.

*Что делать, если я прочитал это сообщения после того, как попробовал войти на сайт, а как результат создал новый профиль пользователя?*

Самым эффективным способом является удаление недавно созданной учетной записи и **выполнения шагов описанных в предыдущей секции**. Если вы не хотите удалять новую учетную запись по каким-либо причинам, пожалуйста, пройдите процесс объединения профилей.

1. Перейдите на форму обратной связи https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact.
2. Выберете пункт "Мне необходимо объединить мои учётные записи".
3. Заполните и отправьте форму (рис. 3).

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Рис. 3

Пожалуйста, убедитесь, что вы указали ссылки на учётные записи с одного и того же домена. Объединить учётные записи с разных доменов невозможно!

*Как объединить учётную запись ХэшКода с существующей учётной записью Stack Exchange (Stack Overflow)?*

Первое, что следует сделать - это выполнить шаги описанные в первой секции - **восстановить доступ к профилю ХэшКод с помощью формы восстановления доступа**. В этом случае, если вы использовали одинаковый регистрационные данные на обоих проектах, ваши учётные записи будут объединены автоматически.

Если после выполнения всех шагов из раздела восстановления доступа ваши учетные записи все еще разные, пожалуйста, сообщите мне об этом на почту nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com

Comment: А вот у меня вопрос - учёт репутации\уважения для stackoverflow и **ru.stackoverflow** отдельный? Т.е. вот сейчас у меня на ru 2.5к очков, а на не ru, 110, из которых вчера какие-то левые 100 очков не за что...

Comment: Да, учет отдельный, поскольку SO и Ru.SO -- это два отдельных сообщества с отдельными профилями.

Comment: Опечатки: Данные шаги должны быть первым (первыми); если я прочитал это сообщения после того (сообщение); способом являет удаление (является); и выполнения шагов (выполнение);
Выберете пункт (выберите)

Comment: @Dmi7ry Спасибо, поправил.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а проф. сообщество с анкетами для рекрутеров не переехало вместе с ХешКодом? Или оно не было особо актуально?

Comment: Сложность импорта данных намного выше количество резюме. Существует прекрасный сайт http://careers.stackoverflow.com. Вы можете создать на нем свой профиль.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб 100 очков были за связывание записей из разных сайтов. Они даются один раз на каждом сайте сети stackexchange, где вы регистрируетесь. Позволяют преодолеть новичковые ограничения на комментарии и остальное.