# Почему я не могу завершить регистрацию на Stack Overflow на русском?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено

У меня есть аккаунты на [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) и на [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/). Я могу задавать вопросы на русском сайте, но мне всегда показывается сообщение "Finish registration". Я пробовала авторизоваться через социальные сети: Facebook, Google и т.д., но сообщение с предложением завершить регистрацию все равно появляется.

Кто-нибудь может помочь с моей проблемой?
Что я должна сделать, чтобы завершить регистрацию?

P.S: Я не могу задать вопрос на [Stack Overflow на русском Meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/), поскольку моя регистрация, якобы, не завершена.

Comment: Похоже, проблема решена. Добро пожаловать. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да, спасибо! Проблема была решена! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279597/cant-finish-registration-in-stackoverflow-ru/279685#279685

Answer (score 6):

Спасибо за отзыв! С большой вероятностью, что–то пошло не так в процессе восстановления доступа к вашей учётной записи. Возможно, вы были зарегистрированы на ХэшКоде? Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [инструкцию по восстановлению доступа к учётной записи ХэшКод](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/24/). Если это не поможет, пожалуйста, пишите, решим проблему вместе!

Comment: Я никогда не была зарегистрирована на ХэшКод.

Comment: @Lucky_girl Пожалуйста, подскажите, получилось ли закончить регистрацию согласно рекомендациям в ответе?

Comment: Я перешла по ссылке http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery , на эмейл пришла ссылка для изминения пароля, изменила пароль, после чего появился экран, что я завершила регистрацию, но по факту ничего не поменялось мне до сих пор пишет, что я не завершила регистрацию.

Comment: @Lucky_girl Спасибо! Постараюсь выяснить в ближайшее время, что пошло не так.

Comment: Спасибо, буду ждать!

Comment: А в чём проблема была? Может ли она повторится у кого-то ещё?

Comment: @Other Проблема была в неверном статусе учетной записи, который был присвоен после ассоциации. Скорее всего, именно такой проблемы более возникнуть не должно.